# How to check the number of arguments of a callback function before calling the function

Tags: javascript

I have

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    if (callback.arguments.length == 1) { // Need help here
        // Some logic here
        callback(obj1);
    }
    else {
        // Some other logic here
        callback(obj1, obj2);
    }
}

if (someLogic) {
    doSomething(function(arg1) { ... });
}
else {
    doSomething(function(arg1, arg2) { ... });
}
```

How can I check the length of the callback's arguments before calling it?

Comment: Use `arguments.length` instead of `callback.arguments.length`

Comment: Just use arguments.length

Comment: arguments.length will give me the length of the arguments for the doSomething method, which is 1. I need the length of the callback function's arguments, the anonymous functions passed into doSomething, before I call the callback

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `callback.length`.

The `length` property on any function tells you [the number of named arguments that function expects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).